# Porque al traer un registro DateTime en la BD en mi WindowsForms aparece con la hora adelantada

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql, windows-forms

Buenas tengo unos registro en mi BD Posgre, y al traerlo me aparece con 5 horas de adelanto.

En mi BD sale `2020-01-14 18:37:50-05` y al traerlo aparece `14/01/2020 23:37:50` no entiendo porque ocurre esto

```
 while (reader.Read())
 {
   Dates _date = new Dates();
          
   _date.Fecha_I = DateTime.Parse(reader[2].ToString());
 }
```

He intentado lo siguiente sin exito alguno y ademas arroja la excepcion `String '14/01/2020 23:37:50' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

```
_date.Fecha_I = DateTime.ParseExact(reader[2].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

_date.Fecha_I = DateTime.ParseExact(reader[2].ToString(), "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: No está mal. Es algo de zonas horarias. Podrías decirnos cuál es tu zona horaria y qué devuelve reader[2]?

Comment: Es correcto, si te fijas la fecha que se guarda en tu bd al final tiene -05

Comment: @Japv, entonces la solucion seria restarle

Comment: No tienes que restar nada, todo esta correcto

Comment: @Mateo, mi zona hora es (UTC-5)‎

Comment: @Japv, no puede ser correcto porque debe traer lo mismo que esta en la BD es decir 2020-01-14 18:37:50-05,

Comment: En la base de datos esta 18:37:50-05, ese -05 al final indica tu zona horaria y 23:37:50 es exactamente lo mismo que 18:37:50-05

Comment: entra aqui: https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/postgresql/zona-horaria-predeterminada-de-postgres/972367577/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si prestas atención, la hora está adelantada 5hs y no es ninguna casualidad.

Aparentemente la hora se está leyendo en UTC. Solo tienes que realizar la conversión a tu zona horaria.

Un ejemplo con una zona con un huso horario similar al tuyo:

```
var ahora = DateTime.UTCNow;
var zonaEST = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("EST")

var ahoraEST = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUTC(ahora, zonaEST)
```

Comment: Gracias @Mateo, con ese ejemplo pude realizar la conversion del time zone y se logra ver la misma fecha que en mi BD